# Invoking google's MAP and navigation app on button click on chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, maps

hi i am trying to open the google's MAP app on a button click on a chrome browser ,i will be getting my lat long fields from my code ,my site works on android phone and will be opened on Chrome browser only.i am using jquery and c#.net

Comment: Can you share an example?  a simepl geo: url should work

Answer (score 0):

If you encode using the geo: uri scheme you should be fine.

For example, I created:

```
<a href="geo:-0.3128432,51.4645338">A GEO LINK</a>
```

And it works fine.

Demo here: http://jsbin.com/atipiw/latest